# Can you have an infinite number of particles that don't form any event horizons?

Tags: black-holes, astrophysics, event-horizon

If you bring two particles of matter close together at some point the combined mass will correspond to black hole with event horizon that encloses both particles.

With an infinite number of particles in a homogeneous distribution, no matter how far apart the particles, the combined mass would form an event horizon that encompassed all the particles.

But could one have a kind of fractal distribution of particles, such that no particle would be inside the event horizon of another group of particles?

As an example with 4 particles. If we split the particles into two pairs so that the event horizon of one pair does not enclose the other pair.

i.e. there may be particles quite close together but as you zoomed out the density would decrease.

Comment: If you have such a density distribution that the mass inside a sphere is proportional to the radius, then sure, why not? The density would have to drop as the square of the radius. In fact, the universe roughly follows this distribution. On one end, you have a black hole in the center of the galaxy. On the other, the Hubble length is close to the Schwarzschild radius of the barionic mass it contains.

Comment: If you have an infinite number of particles, where would the event horizon be? At infinity? Or do you have an infinite number of particles in a finite space?

Comment: @safesphere. That's a good point. I wonder if you could have a rule of nature that event horizons are not allowed to exist. This would constrain the positions of particles and information allowed in the Universe.

Comment: @Stuart. Well for any subset of particles in a sphere, the event horizon would be bigger than the sphere.  Assuming particles are distributed evenly outside the sphere, they have no affect on gravity of matter inside the sphere.

Comment: Well, black holes do exist, so if such a rule is there, it must be more complex. The nature of black holes is still unknown though. For example, it is unclear if the event horizon is real or apparent, what quantum effects happen at the horizon, if it is possible to cross it, and if the Hawking radiation exists. It is pretty obvious though, although rarely understood, that there is nothing inside a black hole.

Comment: @safesphere. They do, it's true. But if all particles are concentrated just on the event horizon boundary as seen from outside, then they are not really "inside" the event horizon. So the rule could hold true even for black holes. In fact that rule would *require* the particles to stay on the boundary. And does an event horizon really exist if nothing can pass through it? A philosophical thought. It would mean that the degrees of freedom of N particles would be less than $\mathbb{R^{3N}}$.

Comment: This is correct and the name of the rule is energy conservation. Black holes are not a result of General Relativity, but of energy conservation. The total energy of a body at infinity is $E=mc^2$. In a free fall, this energy is converted to the energy of the gravitational field $E=\dfrac{GMm}{r}$. Even if you ignore the kinetic energy for simplicity for a moment and equate the above formulas as a limit for energy conservation, you get exactly a half of the Schwarzchild radius of a black hole without GR. Add the kinetic energy and you get the full radius that nothing can cross from outside.

Comment: @safesphere That's interesting. Thanks. A good way to look at it! I wonder using this conservation rule. Can you calculate the spacial degrees of freedom in space of N particles? If such a think makes sense.

Comment: Whether the true horizon exists or not is an open question. According to GR, it does not, because it cannot form in a finite time of any real observer, even the one in a free fall, because he does not have a frame at the horizon and while he is above, there is no horizon. Essentially this is a classical picture. I suspect however that quantum effects take over at the horizon. If this is true, then matter disappears at the horizon completely and it's energy is converted to the energy of the curved spacetime. So a black hole is an empty self-curved spacetime. Then the horizon exists.